# Spotlight and apple.developer.com (?) using an unusal amount of CPU

Tags: macos

Sporadically, my OS X 10.10.2 machine start using a crazy amount of CPU for no apparent reason, with all the disadvantages that come with it (battery drain, overheating, ...).

If I look at Activity Monitor, here is what I see:

[image: CPU usage in activity monitor]

Spotlight is using 180%, while a process named `https://developer.apple.com` (?).

This will go on for minutes.

In fact, I have never seen this resolving on its own, I need to terminate `https://developer.apple.com` in order to bring down the CPU usage to a sane level. Terminating that process makes Spotlight go back to a reasonable CPU Usage.

FYI, I often use XCode, but just quitting XCode when this is happening does not fix the issue.

What is happening, why is there a process called `https://developer.apple.com` and is there a way to avoid this situation?

Comment: It seems to me that Spotlight is performing indexing. This usually takes a lot of CPU power.

Comment: bear in mind Activity Monitor shows usage per core, so you would usually divide that by 8 to get the true figure

Comment: @Tetsujin sure, thanks for clarifying. I will edit to make it more clear.